# mysql error: Llike operator throws error

Tags: mysql

I dont know what is the problem in my query but it throws some error.

```
select * from tbl_emailswipes where 
         eswipes_title like '% 1939 %',
      or eswipes_title like '% 1939%',
      or eswipes_title like '%1939 %',
      or eswipes_title like '%1939%',
      or eswipes_text  like '% 1939 %',
      or eswipes_text  like '% 1939%',
      or eswipes_text  like '%1939 %',
      or eswipes_text  like '%1939%'
```

and the error is

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '
>
> ```
>       or eswipes_title like '% 1939%',
>       or eswipes_title like '%' at line 2
> ```

Please help solve this issue

Comment: You don't need the `,`.

Comment: remove commas after like

Comment: @Giorgos Betsos thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No commas are needed.  But, this would be much more easily written as:

```
select es.*
from tbl_emailswipes es
where concat(' ', es.eswipes_title, ' ') like '% 1939 %' or
      concat(' ', es.eswipes_text, ' ') like '% 1939 %';
```

The logic in this query simplifies the comparisons.  It adds a separator (`' '`) at the beginning and end of the columns.  This makes it much easier to find a word in the pattern.

Comment: Thank you bro for your answer and if there is an explanation, it will be more useful, I really dont understand why you used concat for column name

Answer (score 1):

You are using (,) in your query. Remove that.

```
select * from tbl_emailswipes where 
         eswipes_title like '% 1939 %'
      or eswipes_title like '% 1939%'
      or eswipes_title like '%1939 %'
      or eswipes_title like '%1939%'
      or eswipes_text  like '% 1939 %'
      or eswipes_text  like '% 1939%'
      or eswipes_text  like '%1939 %'
      or eswipes_text  like '%1939%'
```